# "Domains, protocols and ports must match" Error + Fixed div freezing in Chrome

Tags: css, html, fixed, freeze

I'm getting the error below from my website in Chrome from Google Adsense, and it's causing my fixed position div sidebar to freeze. I've looked the error up on here, and some seem to say it's a problem on Google's part (which seems odd it's not fixed), but that it shouldn't affect anything; I see no reason why it would freeze a fixed div.

It doesn't show up in Firefox or IE9, and doesn't cause the problem I'm having there. As soon as the error pops up on the browser console, the sidebar stops moving.

> "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL -My URL- from frame with URL -Google Adsense URL-. Domains, protocols and ports must match."

I'm not sure if I'm allowed to post a URL to demonstrate. What I think is relevant code is below for my ad and other sidebar.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="leftercontainer">
<div id="lefter">Sidebar.</div></div>

<div id="contenter">Content</div>

<div id="rightercontainer">
<div id="righter" class="center">Google Ad.</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS for this being. I realize some code may be redundant, I'm a beginner. But it does work in all cases except with this error.

```
#container {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width:1020px;}
#leftercontainer{float:left; width:129px;}
#lefter {position:fixed; width:129px; margin-left:10px; margin-right:11px;}
#contenter {margin-left:155px; float:left; width: 680px;}
#rightercontainer {float:right; width:129px;}
#righter {width:129px;}
```

EDIT: So, for my above problem I changed the Adsense code to 'asynchronous' loading on Google's end, but it turns out it that doesn't fix anything, leaving a slightly different error, 
"Blocked a frame with origin "Ad URL" from accessing a frame with origin "My URL". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."

But I have a different, more direct cause now; on this page, only in Chrome:
http://www.eh-hem.net/chat.php

The fixed position sidebar (which you can see the code for above) freezes straight away. I think it's fairly obvious it's the embedded chatbox, which has this code:

```
<embed wmode="transparent" src="http://www.xatech.com/web_gear/chat/chat.swf"
quality="high" width="540" height="405" name="chat" FlashVars="id=92787532"
align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
pluginspage="http://xat.com/update_flash.php" />
```

No errors show on the javascript console, unlike the Ads did. A quirk is that if I resize the page, the sidebar moves to position, but does not work when I scroll. Does no one else get the same error on this page?

Comment: It should be fine to post your link. Is your site `https://` and the adsense link `http://` ?

Comment: 'www.eh-hem.net'. The error occurs on any page, to test I usually scroll up and down rapidly for about 5 seconds in Chrome, change pages if it doesn't, but it breaks fairly consistently. The links are both just http://, so it can't be that. I'm becoming a bit resigned at this point that it's probably some issue with the Ads themselves, I may not be able to do anything about it...

Comment: Hm, strange. FWIW, I played around with it in Chrome (Mac) and couldn't replicate what you are describing.

Comment: I've appended my question with a more reliable example of div freezing, let me know if it causes the issue on your end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answered in comments and edits. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I seem to have solved my issue... it was a problem on my end, regarding Chrome and Flash Player if I understand it? Animated Ads were causing my issues along with the chatbox... this solved it, though I'm not entirely sure why that would stop the domain/protocol/ports error: [GIF images in Chrome loading slow and/or other problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874065/gif-images-in-chrome-loading-slow-and-or-other-problems)

Comment: Ah, sorry for not appending it as an answer, thanks. Google's ads seem to cause me many problems, I've had to remove them again lately due to other odd issues.