# GIF images in Chrome loading slow and/or other problems

Tags: google-chrome, gif

I am experiencing problems with Chrome and animated .Gif in which they frozen, are slow loading, show screen tearing animations and etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1- Type `chrome://plugins` into the address bar

2- Click the [image: Details button] button on the right side to expand the plugins.

3- Look for the PPAPI PepperFlash plugin.

[image: PPAPI PepperFlash plugin]

4- Click Disable

If you already have the official Adobe version of Flash installed, it should show up right under the pepperflash plugin listing

[image: Official Adobe version of Flash installed]

5- Leave this one enabled.
Otherwise go download the official one from adobe (http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/)

6- Clear the cache. Restart chrome.

**Note:** Pepperflash re-enables itself after Chrome updates so look out for that. Seems that this bug is fixed in the Chrome dev builds, so it might be fixed in an update sooner or later.

Source: http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=502191

Comment: It is not a great practice, to ask your users to install plugins.

Comment: Agreed. This is supposed, though, to be a temporary solution -it works for me for the time being and none of our clients has of yet complained about this-, until someone else can show a better way.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using the animated GIFs as a background image on an element? Chrome is known to have problems with this. If you can find a way to use them in the actual markup, Chrome will serve them fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you use AJAX requests on the page and these are synchronized ( `async: false` in jquery ), this can be happening in opera/chrome.

AJAX is defaultly asynchronous, so if you did not explicitly state `async: false`, you do not have to state `async: true` and this answer might not help you.

Try deleting the line containing `async: false`.